# How can I prove that $\frac{a}{2} + \frac{x}{a} \geq \sqrt{2x}$

Tags: inequality, elementary-functions

How can I prove the inequality

$$
\frac{a}{2} + \frac{x}{a} \geq \sqrt{2x}
$$
for positive $a$ and $x$.

It seems simple, but I don't see a way to prove it.

Comment: Look up “inequality between arithmetic and geometric mean”

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}-\sqrt{\frac{x}{a}}\right)^2\geq0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Since everyone here is positive, compare the squares:
$$\Bigl(\frac{a}{2} + \frac{x}{a}\Bigr)^2=\frac{a^2}{4} + \frac{x^2}{a^2}+ x \geq  2x \iff \frac{a^2}{4} + \frac{x^2}{a^2}- x=\Bigl(\frac{a}{2}-\frac{x}{a}\Bigr)^2\ge 0. $$

Comment: You probably mean $(\frac{a}{2} + \frac{x}{a})^2$ on the left-hand side.

Comment: Oh! yes, of course. Thanks for pointing it!